# Disallow common sub-page of several directories while allowing the directories themselves

Tags: url, robots.txt

I have the following structure

`http://example.com/universities/UNIVERSITY_ID/review`

I am trying to disallow the review page, but keep the page of UNIVERSITY_ID which is dynamic.

how can I accomplish this in the `robots.txt`?

would this work?

```
Disallow: /universities/*/review
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wildcard is better solution to tackle this issue.

```
User-agent: *
disallow: /*review$
```

reference: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72722/can-we-use-regex-in-robots-txt-file-to-block-urls